# Error en peticion Ajax con JQuery: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy haciendo una petición Ajax con JQuery para rellenar un formulario, pero cuando hace la petición me marca error, lo raro es que en otro equipo el código me funciona normal, no se si se deba a la configuración de mi servidor o algo, ya habilite las librerías de PDO en el archivo **`PHP.ini`** y aun así tengo el error, coloco el código de mi petición para ver si alguien sabe cual es la falla:

```
const editar_vehiculo=(id)=>{
    //  window.location.replace("incidentes_info.php?id="+id);
    alert('Editar vehiculo'+$("#Token_CSRF").val())
    
    $.ajax({
        url:'models/ajax/ajax_vehiculos_robados_cmd.php',
        data:{"xCMD":"SeleccionarVehiculo","xToken":$("#Token_CSRF").val(),"xIdVehiculo":id},
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'JSON',
        beforeSend : function(){
            $("#ModalLoading").modal({
                                show:true,
                                backdrop: 'static',
                                keyboard: false
                            });

            $('#btnEditarVehiculoRobado').show();
            $('#btnGuardarVehiculoRobado').hide();
        },
        success : function(res) {
            alert("entra al success"+res.mensaje)
            let id_entidad_aux=0;
            (res.info.id_entidad_propietario.length <2) ? id_entidad_aux='0'+res.info.id_entidad_propietario : id_entidad_aux=res.info.id_entidad_propietario;
            let id_entidad_aux_robo=0;
            (res.info.id_entidad_robo.length <2) ? id_entidad_aux_robo='0'+res.info.id_entidad_robo : id_entidad_aux_robo=res.info.id_entidad_robo;
            let id_origen_aux=0;
            if(res.info.id_origen_placa!=null){

                (res.info.id_origen_placa.length <2) ? id_origen_aux='0'+res.info.id_origen_placa : id_origen_aux=res.info.id_origen_placa;
            }
            // alert(id_entidad_aux)
            $('#ModalLoading').modal('hide');
            $('#txtIdAgraviado').val(res.info.id_vehiculo)
            $('#htxtIdAgraviado').val(res.info.id_vehiculo)
            $('#txtNombrePropietario').val(res.info.nombre_propietario)
            $('#txtApellidoPaternoPropietario').val(res.info.apellido_propietario_p)
            $('#txtApellidoMaternoPropietario').val(res.info.apellido_propietario_m)
            $('#selectEntidadPropietario').val(id_entidad_aux)
            $('#selectEntidadPropietario').change()
            cargarMunicipios('Propietario', id_entidad_aux,res.info.id_municipio_propietario);
            // console.log('id municipio propietario'+res.info.id_municipio_propietario)
            // $('#selectMuncipioDomicilioPropietario').val('0'+res.info.id_municipio_propietario)
            // $("#selectMuncipioDomicilioPropietario").selectpicker("refresh");
            $('#txtCallePropietario').val(res.info.calle_propietario)
            $('#txtNumeroExteriorPropietario').val(res.info.num_exterior_propietario)
            $('#txtNumeroInteriorPropietario').val(res.info.num_interior_propietario)
            $('#txtColoniaPropietario').val(res.info.colonia_propietario)
            $('#txtCodigoPostalPropietario').val(res.info.codigo_postal_propietario)
            $('#txtTelefonoPropietario').val(res.info.telefono_propietario)
            
            $('#selectEntidadRobo').val(id_entidad_aux_robo)
            $('#selectEntidadRobo').change()
            $('#txtFechaRobo').val(res.info.fecha_robo)
            $('#txtHoraRobo').val(res.info.hora_robo)
            $('#selectMarcaVehiculoRobado').val(res.info.id_vehiculo_marca)
            $('#selectMarcaVehiculoRobado').change()
            $('#txtModeloVehiculoRobado').val(res.info.modelo)
            $('#txtNumMotorVehiculoRobado').val(res.info.numero_motor)
            $('#txtPlacasVehiculoRobado').val(res.info.numero_placas)
            $('#selectOrigenPlaca').val(id_origen_aux)
            $('#selectOrigenPlaca').change()
            $('#txtPlacaExtranjeraVehiculo').val(res.info.placa_extranjero)
            $('#selectTipoServicioVehiculo').val(res.info.tipo_servicio_vehiculo)
            $('#selectTipoServicioVehiculo').change()
            $('#txtColorVehiculoRobado').val(res.info.color)
            $('#txtSerieVehiculoRobado').val(res.info.numero_serie)
            $('#selectTipoVehiculoRobado').val(res.info.id_vehiculo_tipo)
            $('#selectTipoVehiculoRobado').change()
            $('#txtDescripcionVehiculoRobado').val(res.info.descripcion_vehiculo)
            
            $('#respuesta').show();
            $('#respuesta').html(res);
            $('#loading').hide();

            

        },
        error : function(jqXHR, status, error){
            console.log("entra al error"+error);
            console.log("entra al jqXHR"+jqXHR)
            console.log("entra al status"+status)
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#respuesta').show();
            $('#respuesta').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>Disculpe, existió un problema.</div>');
        }
    });//cierra ajax

    $("#ModalAgregarVehiculoRobado").modal({
                            show:true,
                            backdrop: 'static',
                            keyboard: false
                        });
}
```

Y este es el metodo que recibe la peticion:

```
 case "SeleccionarVehiculo":
        try{
        $xIdVehiculo = ssp_descifrado($_POST['xIdVehiculo']);
        $IdVehiculo = 000037;
        /*Consultamos la información del elemento seleccionado*/
        $sql_seleccion = "SELECT * FROM vehiculos_robados WHERE id_vehiculo=:xidVehiculo";
    
        $select_cat = $pdo->prepare($sql_seleccion);
        $select_cat->bindParam(':xidVehiculo', $xIdVehiculo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $select_cat->execute();
        $seleccionado = $select_cat->fetchObject();
                                    
        $ajax_respuesta["obtenido"] = true;
    
        $ajax_respuesta["id"]       = $xIdVehiculo; 
        $ajax_respuesta["info"]     = $seleccionado;
        }catch (Exception $e){
            $ajax_respuesta["obtenido"] = false;
            $ajax_respuesta["error"]       = $e->getMessage();  

        }                               
        echo json_encode($ajax_respuesta);                              
        break;
```

El error que me arroja es este:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1

Pero lo que me parece raro es que en otro equipo el sistema me funciona normal, ya he intentado con servidores como XAMPP y WAMP pero el resultado es el mismo, de hecho todas las peticiones de Ajax del sistema me marcan el mismo error.
Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por lo pronto ese mensaje de error te está indicando que se ha encontrado un `<` (una apertura de etiqueta HTML) al comienzo de la respuesta que esperaba que fuera JSON. Es posible que se trate de un mensaje de advertencia de PHP. ¿Puedes mirar el inspector de red del navegador para ver qué mensaje de advertencia te está apareciendo?

Answer (score 1):

Si revisas el mensaje de error:

> Ajax con JQuery: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position
> 1"

Indica que tu Json encontró este simbolo `<` al inicio y no pertenece a una estructura json, un archivo json puede iniciar únicamente con 2 caracteres:

`{` :  objeto Json

`[` : Array Json

Comment: Pero si lo corro en otro equipo no me marca errores, no hay alguna configuracion que se deba hacer en el apache?